# Using I18n in plain JS

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I'm working on a React project, which I added internationalization from i18nexus, and i'm trying to use the translation in a plain JS file.

index.js
`

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "./i18n.js";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Suspense fallback="loading">
        <App />
      </Suspense>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

`

i18n.js
`

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import HttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

const apiKey = "sQeJnBmSuGryd28mX8s5mQ";
const loadPath = `https://api.i18nexus.com/project_resources/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json?api_key=${apiKey}`;

i18next
  .use(HttpBackend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",

    ns: ["default"],
    defaultNS: "default",

    supportedLngs: ["en", "fr"],

    backend: {
      loadPath: loadPath
    }
  });
export default i18next;
```

`

Data.js

`

```
import i18next from "./i18n.js";

export const NavigationMenu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "home",
    text: i18next.t("menu_home"),
    path: "/"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "shop",
    text: i18next.t("menu_shop"),
    path: "/shop"
  }
];
```

`

and this is where i want to map my data :
`

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import { NavigationMenu } from "../Data.js";
function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header__menu">
        <ul>
          {NavigationMenu.map(item => (
            <li>{item.text}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

`

Hope you understood the assignement, and thank you for you help.

I'm trying to add i18n translations to a plain JS file and then use them in a React component by maping throught them.

Answer (score 0):

i18next needs to finish loading the translations before you define `NavigationMenu`.

The easiest way is to render the translation in the component:

```
export const NavigationMenu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "home",
    text: "menu_home",
    path: "/"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "shop",
    text: "menu_shop",
    path: "/shop"
  }
];
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import { NavigationMenu } from "../Data.js";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

function Header() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header__menu">
        <ul>
          {NavigationMenu.map(item => (
            <li>{t(item.text)}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```